# Java - Singleton is causing null errors

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, singleton, factory

I made a DAO class with factory method and the specific DAO returns singleton, a single instance of the DAO.  But I been tracing it and its being created but I try to call on it and it always null.

Just to explain the storage factory

I call on DAOFactory to get RAMDAOFactory to get to RAMUserDAO
If there is better way to handle RAM, Serialization and SQL type DAOs or CRUD please let me know.

class that I'm calling the storage from.

```
public class Registration
{
    private UserDAO userStorage;
    private static Logger   log = LogClass.getLog();

    Registration(DAOFactoryType typeDataStorage)
    {
        userStorage = DAOFactory.getDAOFactory(typeDataStorage).getUserDAO();
        log.trace("insdie Reg");

    }

    void addUser(String userName, String password, UserType... args)
            throws Exception
        {

            List<UserType> userTypes = new ArrayList<UserType>(args.length);
            for (UserType userType : args)
                {
                    log.trace("userType " + userType);
                    userTypes.add(userType);
                }

            User newUser = new DefaultUser(userName, password, userTypes);
            log.trace("newUser " + newUser);


            if (userStorage != null)
                {
                    userStorage.insert(newUser);
                }
            else
                {
                    log.trace("userStorage null");
                }

        }

}
```

This is my DAOFactory

```
public abstract class DAOFactory
{
    private static Logger   log = LogClass.getLog();

    public abstract TradeDAO getTradeDAO();

    public abstract UserDAO getUserDAO();

    public abstract LogDAO getLogDAO();

    public static DAOFactory getDAOFactory(DAOFactoryType factoryType)
        {   
            switch (factoryType)
                {
                case SQL:
                    return new SQLDAOFactory();
                case RAM:
                     log.trace("insdie RAM");
                    return new RAMDAOFactory();
                case SERIAL:
                    return new SerialDAOFactory();

                default:
                    return null;
                }
        }
}
```

RAMDAOFactory

```
public class RAMDAOFactory extends DAOFactory
{
    private static Logger   log = LogClass.getLog();

    private TradeDAO ramTradeDAO;
    private UserDAO ramUserDAO;
    private LogDAO ramLogDAO;

    public RAMDAOFactory()
    {
        log.trace("insdie RAMDAOFactory");
            RAMUserDAO.getRAMUserDAO();     
            RAMTradeDAO.getRAMTradeDAO();       
            RAMLogDAO.getRAMLogDAO();       
    }

    @Override
    public TradeDAO getTradeDAO()
        {
            return ramTradeDAO;
        }

    @Override
    public UserDAO getUserDAO()
        {
            return ramUserDAO;
        }

    @Override
    public LogDAO getLogDAO()
        {
            return ramLogDAO;
        }

}
```

This is my  UserDAO

```
public class RAMUserDAO implements UserDAO
{
    /*
     * Map<Integer, List<byte[]>> userHash; List<byte[]> arrayHashSalt;
     */

    private static  RAMUserDAO userDAO = null;
    private Map<String, User> userList;
    private static Logger   log = LogClass.getLog();

    private RAMUserDAO()
     {
        userList = new HashMap<String, User>();
         log.trace("insdie RAMUserDAO constructor");
    }

    public static RAMUserDAO getRAMUserDAO()
        {
             log.trace("insdie getRAMUserDAO");

             if(userDAO == null) {
                 log.trace("insdie new RAMUserDAO()");
                 userDAO = new RAMUserDAO();
              }

            /*if (userDAO == null)
            {
                synchronized (RAMUserDAO.class)
                {
                    if (userDAO == null)
                    {
                        userDAO = new RAMUserDAO();
                    }
                }
            }*/

            return userDAO;
        }



    @Override
    public void insert(User user) throws Exception
        {
            log.trace("insdie insert");
            userList.put(user.getUserName(), user);
        }
    }
```

The oversight was in RAMDAOFactory and fix was:

```
public class RAMDAOFactory extends DAOFactory
{
    private static Logger log = LogClass.getLog();

    @Override
    public TradeDAO getTradeDAO()
        {
            return RAMTradeDAO.getRAMTradeDAO();
        }

    @Override
    public UserDAO getUserDAO()
        {
            return RAMUserDAO.getRAMUserDAO();
        }

    @Override
    public LogDAO getLogDAO()
        {
            return RAMLogDAO.getRAMLogDAO();
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've called the methods

```
public RAMDAOFactory()
{
    log.trace("insdie RAMDAOFactory");
    RAMUserDAO.getRAMUserDAO();     
    RAMTradeDAO.getRAMTradeDAO();       
    RAMLogDAO.getRAMLogDAO();       
}
```

but you haven't assigned their value to anything

```
@Override
public UserDAO getUserDAO()
{
    return ramUserDAO;
}
```

Either always call

```
RAMUserDao.getRAMUserDAO();
```

when you want to return the `UserDAO` or assign it to `ramUserDAO` and return that.

Comment: Thank you. What a oversight.  I made the fix. Any criticism on the class now, RAMDAOFactory, or any other part of the code?

Comment: @user3590149 Your factories are not really factories. They don't create anything.